Use of C# functions in Python
I am currently trying to integrate some C# functions into my Python project. However, I am encountering some problems.
For example, I found the following instructions on the Internet:
https://medium.com/@mhmdjmala51/using-c-in-python-is-not-difficult-anymore-dbe5c3251431
My Python code looks like this:
import clr
import sys



clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\XXXX\bin\Debug\net8.0\MyAwesomePlugin.dll")

from MyAwesomePlugin import GetBotInventory

and the C# Code:

namespace MyAwesomePlugin;

#pragma warning disable CA1812 // ASF uses this class during runtime
[UsedImplicitly]
public class MyAwesomePlugin : IGitHubPluginUpdates {
    public string Name => nameof(MyAwesomePlugin);
    public string RepositoryName => "JustArchiNET/ASF-PluginTemplate";
    public Version Version => typeof(MyAwesomePlugin).Assembly.GetName().Version ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(Version));

    public Task OnLoaded() {
        ASF.ArchiLogger.LogGenericInfo($"Hello {Name}!");
        ASF.ArchiLogger.LogGenericInfo($"Es funktioniert JAJAJAJAJA!");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public static async Task GetBotInventory(string bot, string SteamID) {
        
        
        if (true) {
            var inventory = Bot.GetBot("bot16").ArchiHandler.GetMyInventoryAsync(730, 2);


            if (inventory != null) {
                ASF.ArchiLogger.LogGenericInfo($"Inventar für Bot 'bot16' erfolgreich abgerufen. Anzahl Items:");
                string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(inventory, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
                Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
            } else {
                ASF.ArchiLogger.LogGenericWarning("Konnte das Inventar nicht abrufen.");
            }
        }
    }

I still always get the error message:
from MyAwesomePlugin import GetBotInventory
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyAwesomePlugin'

The namespace of my C# DDL is called MyAwesomePlugin and a method from the DDL is called GetBotInventory.
I have seen this error several times on the Internet, but have not yet been able to find a fix that has resolved it for me. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Maybe start out by following the tutorial blog exactly, get that going, then paste in your more complex code and see if it breaks

Unfortunately, exactly the same problem occurs,

by using sys.path.append to specify the file path in the sample project from the internet, it then works. However, the same fix does not work for my own project, where I am still faced with the error.
